# how to create foreign keys for parent-child relations on a single table?

Tags: mysql

Example:

```
id | name | parent_id |
```

As you can imagine, parent_id must point to a valid id in the same table.

I'd like to 
- disallow parent row deletion if there are any children
- disallow child editing of parent_id
- if parent_id for some reason would change, all child rows must be updated on field parent_id

how to create the foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think should be something like following

```
create contraint `my_foreign_key`
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
REFERENCES my_table(id)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```